# New PostgreSQL 9.1 configuration doesn’t work

Tags: postgresql

I changed the length of table names in PostgreSQL in the file `pg_config_manual.h` (in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\include`) to 128. Then I reloaded the new configuration by selecting menu "Reload Configuration" under the menu PostgreSQL 9.1 in start menu. Also, I restarted the PostgreSQL. But the change did not take effect. Length of table names in my database still has the limit 64 characters.

How to solve this problem? I am using PostgreSQL 9.1 on Windows 7 Professional.

Answer (score 4):

pg_config_manual.h is not a configuration file, it's part of the source code. After a change in the source code, you have to compile all the code and install the program you just compiled.

Changing the max length for names is not trivial.

Answer (score 3):

in this case, you need recompile PostgreSQL source code. Any changes in pg_config_manual.h needs recompilation - this is not classical config.